# Groupby in dataframe and pass a list of complete rows to reduction function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have:

```
import pandas as pd

d = { id':  [0,    1,     2,   3,    4,    5,      6,   7,     8,      9],
d =  'date':[13,   7,     6,   12,   18,   11,     17,  5,     3,      17], 
     'foo': ['abc','def','def','abc','klm','abc', 'klm','xyz', 'pqr',  'klm'],
     'bar': ['123','456','333','123','111','123', '111', '331', '555', '111'],
     'cnt': [2,     0,    0,    1,    2,    0,     0,    0,      0,     0 ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    id  date    foo bar cnt

0   0   13      abc 123 2
1   1   7       def 456 0
2   2   6       def 333 0
3   3   12      abc 123 1
4   4   18      klm 111 2
5   5   11      abc 123 0
6   6   17      klm 111 0
7   7   5       xyz 331 0
8   8   3       pqr 555 0
9   9   17      klm 111 0
```

Reduction function, which for now just prints its argument, which is a series:

```
def fun(sr):
   print(sr.keys())
   for item in sr.iteritems(): 
       print(item)
   print('----')
```

Group by `foo` and `bar`:

```
df.groupby(['foo', 'bar']).date.agg([fun])
```

I need to pass to reduction function not just `date` values but a list of rows matching `foo` and `bar` values in `groupby`. From this list I need then to build a single dictionary where keys are `id`-s from my `df` and values are `dates`. This dictionaries should be added as a separate column `dicts` to original dataframe `df`.

**Update**: complete example of what I need to get:

```
    id  date    foo bar cnt dicts

0   0   13      abc 123 2   {('abc',123): [(0,13), (3,12), (5,11) }
1   1   7       def 456 0   {('def',456):[(1,7)]}
2   2   6       def 333 0   {('def',333):[(2,6)]}
3   3   12      abc 123 1   {('abc','123'): [(0,13), (3,12), (5,11) }
4   4   18      klm 111 2   {('klm',111):[(4,18),(6,17),(9,17)]}
5   5   11      abc 123 0   {('abc','123'): [(0,13), (3,12), (5,11) }
6   6   17      klm 111 0   {('klm',111):[(4,18),(6,17),(9,17)]}
7   7   5       xyz 331 0   {('xyz',331):[(7,5)]}
8   8   3       pqr 555 0   {('pqr',555):[(8,3)]}
9   9   17      klm 111 0   {('klm',111):[(4,18),(6,17),(9,17)]}
```

Any ideas how to this with `groupby` or maybe some other way?

Comment: hmm, i doubt we can transform a dictionary to the original length of the dataframe since a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. instead of a dictionary will it be okay to have a list of tuples with the values in the desired column?

Comment: Instead of a dictionary it can be just a list of tuples, where tuple is  (id, date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest is create custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def fun(sr):
    vals = list(map(tuple, sr[['id','date']].to_numpy().tolist()))
    sr['dicts'] = [{sr.name:vals}] * len(sr)
    return sr
```

Solution for oldier pandas versions:

```
def fun(sr):
    vals = list(map(tuple, sr[['id','date']].values.tolist()))
    sr['dicts'] = [{sr.name:vals}] * len(sr)
    return sr

df = df.groupby(['foo', 'bar']).apply(fun)
print (df)
  id  date  foo  bar  cnt                                          dicts
0   0    13  abc  123    2  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
1   1     7  def  456    0                     {('def', '456'): [(1, 7)]}
2   2     6  def  333    0                     {('def', '333'): [(2, 6)]}
3   3    12  abc  123    1  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
4   4    18  klm  111    2  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
5   5    11  abc  123    0  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
6   6    17  klm  111    0  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
7   7     5  xyz  331    0                     {('xyz', '331'): [(7, 5)]}
8   8     3  pqr  555    0                     {('pqr', '555'): [(8, 3)]}
9   9    17  klm  111    0  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: @dokondr - It working in `pandas 0.24+`, if use lower pandas version use `.values` instead  `.to_numpy()`

Comment: After change that you have suggested: vals = list(map(tuple, sr[['id','date']].values().tolist())) <====> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: @dokondr - It is `.values`, not `.values()`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
df["id_date"]=list(zip(df["id"], df["date"]))
gr=df.groupby(["foo", "bar"])

df=df.set_index(["foo", "bar"]).merge(gr["id_date"].agg(list).rename("dicts"), left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index().drop("id_date", axis=1)
df["dicts"]=list(zip(list(zip(df["foo"], df["bar"])), df["dicts"]))

df["dicts"]=df["dicts"].map(lambda x: {x[0]: x[1]})
```

Output:

```py
   foo  ...                                          dicts
0  abc  ...  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
1  abc  ...  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
2  abc  ...  {('abc', '123'): [(0, 13), (3, 12), (5, 11)]}
3  def  ...                     {('def', '333'): [(2, 6)]}
4  def  ...                     {('def', '456'): [(1, 7)]}
5  klm  ...  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
6  klm  ...  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
7  klm  ...  {('klm', '111'): [(4, 18), (6, 17), (9, 17)]}
8  pqr  ...                     {('pqr', '555'): [(8, 3)]}
9  xyz  ...                     {('xyz', '331'): [(7, 5)]}

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Try upgrading your ```pandas```: ```pip3 install --upgrade pandas``` (or ```pip```)

Comment: For the downvoter: what seems to be wrong with my solution?

Comment: hmm, not me, plus1

Comment: Not me either, on the contrary - I was trying to upvote, but the stackoverflow system prevents me to do so, don't know why (